# How do you increase the default volume of MuseScore?

Tags: musescore

I am using the [MuseScore](http://musescore.org) music notation program on Windows 7.

For audio playback in MuseScore, I am using the default [General MIDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_MIDI) virtual instrument sample library in Windows 7 [the [Microsoft GS Wavetable Synth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_GS_Wavetable_SW_Synth#Microsoft_GS_Wavetable_SW_Synth) from Windows Media Player].

The overall volume output is too low, so I have to turn my computer volume way up.

I'm not the only person with this issue as seen [here](http://musescore.org/en/node/12564)

I found that you can up the volume in the [Mixer](http://musescore.org/en/handbook/change-and-adjust-sounds), but I shouldn't have to max out every instrument and lower every other program's volume, so is there a way to up the output of MuseScore so that it's a decent level from the start?

**(extra)**Can I switch from using the Microsoft GS Wavetable Synth from Windows Media Player to some other [General MIDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_MIDI) virtual instrument or orchestral library, such as a [VST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Studio_Technology) sample library of some kind? If so what do you recommend for each price range?

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 :)

Comment: When I did a Google search, I learned that many users on Windows have different suggestions for replacing the Microsoft General MIDI instrument with another freeware or inexpensive sound font or other kind of virtual instrument. With the info I've provided you should be able to search for a better alternative to get better-quality sounds.

Comment: It would be good to get that as a suggestion in answers, is it worth me rewording the question to make it more open than MuseScore?

Comment: Why not post your own separate question, for instance, "How can I replace the default General MIDI instrument in Windows with something better?" But you should not post it on this StackExchange site. That would be off-topic. Try the Audio-Video Production stack at http://avp.stackexchange.com/?as=1

Comment: I'm surprised I couldn't find this question already on there: http://avp.stackexchange.com/questions/8713/how-do-you-change-the-default-windows-midi-with-something-better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you don't want the mixer (F10). You want the master volume. This is found in the play panel (F11). This automatically saves your setting so that you don't have to adjust it every time. You can also find a master volume slider in the Synthesizer panel (Display > Synthesizer).

The other option is to adjust the program's relative volume in Window's volume mixer (not sure if there is a similar feature on Macs). This also seems to remember the last used settings so you're not resetting it every time you use MuseScore.